# Sending random messages every 1 minute with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to use `setInterval()` to send random message every minute but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
var facts = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
client.on("ready", () => {
    let channel = client.channels.get("id");
    setInterval(function() {
        channel.send(facts[fact])
    }, 60000)
})
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is never a good way to explain the problem, even when running the code it is obvious - so explain what is happening or what not that you would expect to.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the discord part - I'm going to assume that part is working properly.

By generating the random fact *outside* of the setInterval function, you will always get the same random fact. This should fix that problem:

```js
var facts = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
client.on('ready', () => {
  let channel = client.channels.get('id')
  setInterval(function() {
    var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length)
    channel.send(facts[fact])
  }, 60000)
})
```

Some explanation:

In this example, you will see a random fact produced every second. Except as the random generator is declared outside the setInterval function, you'll see the same fact.

```js
var facts = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length)
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(facts[fact]) // Every second, this will return _the same_ fact.
}, 1000) // Changed to 1s for testing
```

However, if you move the `var fact` declaration inside the setInterval function, a random fact will be generated each second:

```js
var facts = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
setInterval(function() {
  var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length)
  console.log(facts[fact]) // Every second, this will return a _new random_ fact
}, 1000) // Changed to 1s for testing
```